# PDF forms in Java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, pdfbox

I have a set of forms designed using Word. I need these forms to be filled and saved as PDF. All of that programatically in Java.

I explored the following possibilities:

- Word empty -> PDF AcroForm -> Fill with PDFBox
- Word filled programatically -> Converted to PDF
- Word empty -> XHTML -> Filled and saved as PDF using Flying Saucer
- Word empty -> Converted in special XML for Apache FOP

Until now I'm encountering the following difficulties with the first possibility:

- Very difficult to create dynamic table
- PDFBox not able to manage RTL text correctly

Any good experience with these solutions?

Comment: Are you able to create an empty fillable PDF form? If so, you can use iText to fill the PDF form and flatten it to create filled copies of that form. I've used iText a long time ago and it's good..

Comment: I looked at iText - it is not free and I'm not sure how last free version 2.1.7 performs. Also one of the issue I mentioned is the dynamic table. There is no concept of table in PDF therefore I create it in Word but then I have to pre allocate lot of rows in my table and most of them will generally be empty.

Comment: Oh it's not free anymore? I'd used it when it was free about 7-8 years ago and it did a great job. So, if you can still get hold of a copy of it, you can go probably go ahead. But again, they may not provide any support for such old versions now in case you run into any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar implementation for one of my customers few years back. I used open office to create the template and generated PDF using iText. See if it helps.

Steps:

Creating the template:

1. Open a new document in open office and create a new document. Go to “view” and make the “Form Design” mode
2. Enter the text which will represent the static portion of the template.
3. Once the “Form Design” mode is turned on, the corresponding toolbar will be added as highlighted in the screenshot above. Now click the “Text Box” and insert a text box in the document. Double click the text box and insert the required inputs there.
4. Once the template document is created, save and the export the document as PDF and this document will be used as the template for the PDF creation

Fill up the template using iText:

The next step is to read the template and populate the template to generate PDF dynamically.
iText provides a PdfReader to read PDF files and PdfStamper to modify or add content to a PDF document. Since the template is a PDF file, the PdfReader will read the template and PdfStamper will populate the fields dynamically with real time data. Following are the steps

1.Read the PDF template using the iText PdfReader. The template can be put anywhere in the file system. But in a real life project scenario, it should be placed inside the project folder.

2. Create a PdfStamper with the PdfReader and a ByteArrayOutputStream as parameter.
3. Populate the template fields using the instance of the PdfStamper object. The setField () method takes the key and the value as argument. The “key” should be the “Name” of the text box that was given during the template creation. Please make sure that the “key” is same as the “Name” field. Otherwise the field will not be populated.
4. After populating the required fields, close the PdfStamper with the PdfReader objects.

Reference : http://itext-pdfcreation-template.blogspot.in/